# Custom faker provider for usage with factory boy and pytest

Tags: django, python-3.x, pytest, faker, factory-boy

I am attempting to add some custom faker provider to use with `factory_boy` and `pytest`.

I put the provider in
`faker_providers/foo.py/Provider`.

In `my factories.py` file, I have to import `foo.py` and then register by running:

```py
factory.Faker.add_provider(foo.Provider)
```

I am thinking of using `pytest_sessionstart(session)` to auto-register all the custom provider under `faker_providers`. Is there a way to do that?

Any suggestions for other ways to organize and register custom providers would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of instantiating a Faker to import from conftest, as of 2022, you can do the following inside your conftest file:

```py
from factory import Faker

Faker.add_provider(CustomProvider)
```

And now you can just import `from factory import Faker` wherever you go. This works because the Faker class has a class attribute of type dictionary that saves your new providers.

The reason I put it in conftest is because this is where code is run initially for all pytest. You can also put this in a pytest plugin setup method as well, but I found this the easiest.

---

The other way of doing this that I implemented was to have a utils folder with all my custom providers. Then, in a providers.py, I would add all my providers:

```py
from factory import Faker

from .custom_provider import CustomProvider

for provider in (CustomProvider,):
    Faker.add_provider(provider)
```

Then in conftest.py, I would simply import this file:

```py
import path.to.provider  # noqa
```

This way, I don't clutter my conftest too much.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a design choice and only you know the best answer to it.

However, I would recommend instantiating `faker = Faker()` once for all tests after that adding all `providers` in a configuration file. And import `faker` from that place to everywhere it's needed.

It seems like [`conftest.py`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.7.3/plugins.html) is a good choice for that.